# Exception : No MaterialLocalizations found. when trying to display AlertDialog

Tags: flutter

Trying to display Alert Dialog by calling a function from the parent widget.

Here's the code :

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              popUp(context);
            },
            child: Text("Click"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void popUp(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(title: Text("ok"),);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But getting following Exception :

`I/flutter ( 4041): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4041): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 4041): No MaterialLocalizations found.
I/flutter ( 4041): MyApp widgets require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.
I/flutter ( 4041): Localizations are used to generate many different messages, labels,and abbreviations which are used
I/flutter ( 4041): by the material library. 
I/flutter ( 4041): To introduce a MaterialLocalizations, either use a  MaterialApp at the root of your application to
I/flutter ( 4041): include them automatically, or add a Localization widget with a MaterialLocalizations delegate.
I/flutter ( 4041): The specific widget that could not find a MaterialLocalizations ancestor was:
I/flutter ( 4041):   MyApp
I/flutter ( 4041): The ancestors of this widget were:
I/flutter ( 4041):   [root]`

It reads `use a  MaterialApp at the root of your application` which I have already done. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that the `context` variable you are passing to the `popUp` function is actually from the root. It is not contained inside the `MaterialApp` if that makes sense.

To work around this, you could either refactor your widget to have the `body` be it's own widget, or use a `Builder` like:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Builder(builder: (context) => Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              popUp(context);
            },
            child: Text("Click"),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: How to use  **AlertDialog()**, in case of it doesn't have main().

Answer (score 3):

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home:MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              popUp(context);
            },
            child: Text("Click"),
          ),
        ),
      );
    
  }

  void popUp(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(title: Text("ok"),);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The thing is we have to implement **MaterialApp** inside **runApp()** which is the root of the program.